# how to save model filters in keras

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, keras

I am visualizing my cnn model filters (kernels) using code from [here](https://github.com/julienr/ipynb_playground/blob/master/keras/convmnist/keras_cnn_mnist.ipynb), which is following:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
def nice_imshow(ax, data, vmin=None, vmax=None, cmap=None):
    """Wrapper around pl.imshow"""
    if cmap is None:
        cmap = cm.jet
    if vmin is None:
        vmin = data.min()
    if vmax is None:
        vmax = data.max()
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
    im = ax.imshow(data, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    pl.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
#    pl.savefig("featuremaps--{}".format(layer_num) + '.jpg')

import numpy.ma as ma
def make_mosaic(imgs, nrows, ncols, border=1):
    """
    Given a set of images with all the same shape, makes a
    mosaic with nrows and ncols
    """
    nimgs = imgs.shape[0]
    imshape = imgs.shape[1:]

    mosaic = ma.masked_all((nrows * imshape[0] + (nrows - 1) * border,
                            ncols * imshape[1] + (ncols - 1) * border),
                            dtype=np.float32)

    paddedh = imshape[0] + border
    paddedw = imshape[1] + border
    for i in range(nimgs):
        row = int(np.floor(i / ncols))
        col = i % ncols

        mosaic[row * paddedh:row * paddedh + imshape[0],
               col * paddedw:col * paddedw + imshape[1]] = imgs[i]
    return mosaic


# Visualize weights
W=model.layers[8].get_weights()[0][:,:,0,:]
W=np.swapaxes(W,0,2)
W = np.squeeze(W)
print("W shape : ", W.shape)

pl.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
pl.title('conv1 weights')
nice_imshow(pl.gca(), make_mosaic(W, 8, 8), cmap=cm.binary)
```

I want to save filters images. Generally we use     `fig.savefig("featuremaps-kernel-{}".format(layer_num) + '.jpg')` for saving figures. But it's not working in this case, may be because nice_ function. Please help what command i have to write to save figure using command not manually. Because if there is large network there is lot of manual work.

Comment: how `savefig` is not working? do you get empty images? errors? try using a headless backend like `mpl.use('Agg')` and/or disabling interactive mode with `plt.ioff()`

Comment: i tried all options you mentions, still getting empty images.

Comment: what is the shape of `W`?

Comment: there are 32 filters of size (2x2)

Comment: your code creates [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3rDj.jpg) here with `W=np.random.random(size=(2,2,32))`

Comment: yup thats correct, i found this type of images only, but i my CNN model having several layers, and i  am using many kernels. so i want to save them using looping 9for loop) that's why i want to save them using instructions. not manually. but fig.savefig save empty images

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172498/discussion-between-hitesh-and-filippo).

Comment: `mpl.use('Agg') ` works for me

Comment: @filippo i got got solution in comments only. so how can i press icon of accept answer. i just voted for your comment. Thnx for your help again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue trying to save figures in Keras with `plt.savefig`.
It always resulted in blank images.

I never really found out why it happened, if I recall correctly it only occurred when using multiprocessing, but I may be wrong.

I solved it using a non-interactive backend, which should anyway be the proper choice if you're never going to display them with `plt.show()`.

At the top of your matplotlib imports add

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
```

Also, if you're saving many images like this at some point matplotlib will complain about too many open figures. You should add a `plt.close()` call after each `plt.savefig`.

Sorry about the purely anecdotal answer, maybe someone with better insight will comment.